# How to do optimization with C code in Xcode

Tags: ios, c, xcode, arm

here is a piece of code like this:

```
// example_3
int Add_8K_3(int* in, int* out, int b)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<1024;i++)
    {
        int a0, a1;
        a0 = *in++;
        a1 = *in++;
        *out++ = a0 + b;
        *out++ = a1 + b;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I compile it by both ARMCC and Xcode (by -O3).
But the performance of two results are much different. the cycle number in Xcode is about 3 times than armcc result.
arm asm code

```
    {
                    Add_8K_3 PROC
    ADD      r0,r0,#4
    MOV      r3,#0x400
    PUSH     {r4}                  ;3264
|L1.12|
    SUBS     r3,r3,#1
    LDR      r4,[r0,#-4]           ;3271
    LDR      r12,[r0],#8           ;3271
    ADD      r4,r4,r2              ;3271
    STR      r4,[r1],#8
    ADD      r12,r12,r2
    STR      r12,[r1,#-4]
    BNE      |L1.12|
    POP      {r4}
    MOV      r0,#0
    BX       lr
                    ENDP
}
```

Xcode asm code

```
    {
_Add_8K_3:
    .cfi_startproc
Lfunc_begin3:
    .loc    1 77 0                  @ /Users/Emedia/Desktop/testperformance/testperformance/core.c:77:0
@ BB#0:
    .loc    1 76 19 prologue_end    @ /Users/Emedia/Desktop/testperformance/testperformance/core.c:76:19
    push    {r7, lr}
    mov.w   lr, #0
Ltmp15:
    @DEBUG_VALUE: i <- 0+0
    mov r7, sp
    @DEBUG_VALUE: Add_8K_3:in <- R0+0
    @DEBUG_VALUE: Add_8K_3:out <- R1+0
    @DEBUG_VALUE: Add_8K_3:b <- R2+0
LBB3_1:                                 @ =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
Ltmp16:
    @DEBUG_VALUE: Add_8K_3:in <- R0+0
    @DEBUG_VALUE: Add_8K_3:out <- R1+0
    @DEBUG_VALUE: Add_8K_3:b <- R2+0
    @DEBUG_VALUE: i <- 0+0
    .loc    1 82 9                  @ /Users/Emedia/Desktop/testperformance/testperformance/core.c:82:9
    ldr.w   r12, [r0, lr, lsl #3]
    Ltmp17:
@DEBUG_VALUE: a0 <- R12+0
    add.w   r3, r0, lr, lsl #3
    .loc    1 83 9                  @ /Users/Emedia/Desktop/testperformance/testperformance/core.c:83:9
    ldr.w   r9, [r3, #4]
Ltmp18:
    @DEBUG_VALUE: a1 <- R9+0
    .loc    1 86 9                  @ /Users/Emedia/Desktop/testperformance/testperformance/core.c:86:9
    add.w   r3, r12, r2
    str.w   r3, [r1, lr, lsl #3]
    add.w   r12, r1, lr, lsl #3
    Ltmp19:
    .loc    1 79 20                 @ /Users/Emedia/Desktop/testperformance/testperformance/core.c:79:20
    add.w   lr, lr, #1
    Ltmp20:
@DEBUG_VALUE: i <- LR+0
    .loc    1 87 9                  @ /Users/Emedia/Desktop/testperformance/testperformance/core.c:87:9
    add.w   r3, r9, r2
    str.w   r3, [r12, #4]
Ltmp21:
    .loc    1 79 9                  @ /Users/Emedia/Desktop/testperformance/testperformance/core.c:79:9
    cmp.w   lr, #1024
    bne LBB3_1
Ltmp22:
    @ BB#2:
    movs    r0, #0
    .loc    1 93 5                  @ /Users/Emedia/Desktop/testperformance/testperformance/core.c:93:5
    pop {r7, pc}
Ltmp23:
Lfunc_end3:
}
```

The problem i could get is that
Xcode can't parse the "in[X]" by suitable asm code.
And my question is:
(1) How can i write the C code to generate the asm code that the Xcode could parse "in[X]" to suitable asm code like arm?
(2) Is there some manual to describe the compiler difference with clang and armcc, and tell me how to write C code for iOS by high performance.

Thx.

Comment: Can you post the disassembly?

Comment: It looks like difference is XCode is adding keeping debug values, while armcc doesn't do that. Can't you set XCode to do a release build?

Comment: Hm, as far as I can see, the ARMCC code "looks" a bit more "reasonable" and more reproducible: two LDR, two STR, two ADD and a loop with a counter. That "seems" optimal. In clang's assembly, the counter comes out differently, seems to use more registers, and the code is not that reproducible. The question is, is this intentional for gaining performance, or just worser assembly?

Comment: Apparently you compiled to ARM mode with ARMCC and to Thumb2 with Apple LLVM.

Comment: XCode != compiler - it's an IDE.  It would be helpful if you indicated  which compiler XCode is invoking.

Comment: According to the compiling log, Xcode uses clang:

Comment: According to the compiling log, Xcode uses clang:"
....../usr/bin/clang -x c -arch armv7 -fmessage-length=0 -std=gnu99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings 
-Os  -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -DDEBUG=0 -fstrict-aliasing -Wdeprecated-declarations -g 
-fvisibility=hidden  -miphoneos-version-min=6.1 
-F....../Build/Products/Release-iphoneos -DNS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1 
-MMD -MT dependencies 
-MF ....../Release-iphoneos/.../armv7/core.d 
--serialize-diagnostics ....../Release-iphoneos/.../armv7/core.dia -c core.c -o ....../Release-iphoneos/.../armv7/core.o"

Comment: there are more settings :"-Wint-conversion -Wenum-conversion
-Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wreturn-type 
-Wformat -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wno-unused-function 
-Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value 
-Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow 
-Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion 
-isysroot ...../iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk
-Wno-sign-conversion"

Comment: frankly speaking, i'm not sure the asm code is for release. Because in the asm code it lists "@DEBUG_VALUE: a1 <- R9+0" and there are many lines in the head of code such as ".section __DWARF, __debug_abbrev,regular,debug". And in the log file, there is "-g" in the cmd line. So could you show me how to run it and get the asm code by release mode ?

Comment: There's a misconception here: the debugging hints are in the asm source code. There's no "debug code" left in the disassembly.

Answer (score 1):

While Apple's LLVM generates decent codes, (much better than GCC) it's still no match for the best-in-class ARMCC.

In fact, ARMCC is really really good.

However, your sample is so simple that even the infamous GCC wouldn't fail.

There are two things you messed up with your code :

1. ARMCC did the job in ARM mode, LLVM in Thumb2
2. The XCode binary still contains debug/profiling information. You should change the corresponding options.

NEON could handle the sample function much much faster, but for iOS deployment, you need both AARCH32 and AARCH64 versions, and both quite differ in syntax and register allocations.

If you are trying to learn ARM assembly for optimizations, don't do it. AARCH64's ISA is completely reconstructed and streamlined which means even the worst possible compiler in the world like GCC is capable of generating halfway decent codes.

NEON is a different story though. It might be worth the effort. (but you'll have to write both AARCH32 AND AARCH64 versions)

Comment: Jake, I couldn't see differences in the assembly when explicitly specifying `thumb` or `no-thumb` compiler options, when I made my tests described in my answer. More though, the *range* of accessed integers made the difference.

Comment: Oh, I see. Just wonder why even ARMCC refuses to make use of the sequential memory accesses though (ldr r12,[r0],#4)

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect problem for vectorization.  As Jake noted, vectorization is sometimes avoided because it’s a pain to have separate code paths for each architecture.  In an ideal world, compilers would successfully autovectorize all of these cases and it wouldn’t be an issue.  In the meantime, there are a few other options available.

If you’re targeting iOS / OSX and can limit yourself to clang, the nicest solution for simple loops like these is to use clang “extended vectors”; these let you write vector code that works across architectures:

```
typedef int vector_int __attribute__((ext_vector_type(4),aligned(4)));
const int ints_per_vector = 4;

int Add_8K_3(int *in, int* out, int b) {
  vector_int *vin  = (vector_int *)in;
  vector_int *vout = (vector_int *)out;
  for (int i=0; i<1024/ints_per_vector; i++)
    vout[i] = vin[i] + b;
  return 0;
}
```

This generates decent (not perfect) vector code for all the architectures that clang supports.  E.g. armv7s:

```
0: adds      r3,         r0, r2
   vld1.32  {d18, d19}, [r3]
   adds      r3,         r1, r2
   adds      r2,         #0x10
   cmp.w     r2,         #0x1000
   vadd.i32  q9,         q9, q8
   vst1.32  {d18, d19}, [r3]
   bne       0b
```

arm64:

```
0: ldr       q1,   [x0, x8, lsl #4]
   add.4s    v1,    v1, v0
   str       q1,   [x1, x8, lsl #4]
   add       x8,    x8, 1
   cmp       w8,    #256
   b.ne      0b
```

x86_64:

```
0: movdqu   (%rdi,%rax), %xmm1
   paddd     %xmm0,      %xmm1
   movdqu    %xmm1,     (%rsi,%rax)
   add       $0x10,      %rax
   cmp       $0x1000,    %eax
   jne       0b
```

If you need your code to be portable to other compilers, however, it’s preferable to use intrinsics or rely on compiler optimization instead, and if you really need your code to go absolutely as fast as possible, then some amount of hand-tuning is unavoidable.

Comment: Worth pointing out that in the example given, the compiler can't know that `in` and `out` don't overlap. It has to honour the sequence of operations as written.  Of course, clang gets around this by generating both overlapped and non-overlapped versions of the code and a runtime check.  Which is quite a bit of code.

Comment: According to the asm code, it used the NEON intrinsic,but I don't want it in the example. because in my another example, i will compare the NEON intrinsic by both ARMCC and clang.

Comment: Related info: I've tried to persuade clang to apply auto vectorization for the OPs code. But it didn't kick in, no matter what I tried.

Answer (score 0):

I can only make a guess here:

It seems, the clang optimizer *prefers* to use "immediate offsets" for accessing the input and output arrays. e.g.

```
str.w   r3, [r1, lr, lsl #3]
```

If the offset *exceeds* 1024, the clang optimizer chooses *double* register load and stores with a *register offset*:

Here is a disassembly for when the range of accessed integers exceeds 1024 (1025 in this case):

```
0x79188:  push   {r4, r5, r7, lr}
0x7918a:  add    r7, sp, #8
0x7918c:  str    r8, [sp, #-4]!
0x79190:  movw   r3, #1025
0x79194:  ldrd   r8, r9, [r0]
0x79198:  add.w  r5, r9, r2
0x7919c:  adds   r0, #8
0x7919e:  subs   r3, #1
0x791a0:  add.w  r4, r8, r2
0x791a4:  strd   r4, r5, [r1]
0x791a8:  add.w  r1, r1, #8
0x791ac:  bne    0x79194                   ; Add_8K_3 + 12 at AppDelegate.m:24
0x791ae:  movs   r0, #0
0x791b0:  ldr    r8, [sp], #4
0x791b4:  pop    {r4, r5, r7, pc}
```

When the range of accessed integers exceeds 1800 (`for (int i = 0; i < 1800; ++i)`) clang  will again choose to use "immediate offsets" with single register load and stores:

```
0x94180:  push   {r7, lr}
0x94182:  mov.w  lr, #0
0x94186:  mov    r7, sp
0x94188:  ldr.w  r12, [r0, lr, lsl #3]
0x9418c:  add.w  r3, r0, lr, lsl #3
0x94190:  ldr.w  r9, [r3, #4]
0x94194:  add.w  r3, r12, r2
0x94198:  str.w  r3, [r1, lr, lsl #3]
0x9419c:  add.w  r12, r1, lr, lsl #3
0x941a0:  add.w  lr, lr, #1
0x941a4:  add.w  r3, r9, r2
0x941a8:  str.w  r3, [r12, #4]
0x941ac:  cmp.w  lr, #1800
0x941b0:  bne    0x94188                   ; Add_8K_3 + 8 at AppDelegate.m:24
0x941b2:  movs   r0, #0
0x941b4:  pop    {r7, pc}
```

Not sure, why - maybe heuristics which suggest the best performance.